# Writing excel functions in vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm trying to write the match and index functions as vba code but its not working due to several errors.

In excel, I have a table `R5:AD33`
I used to match functions to get my row and column number to input into my index function.

```
=MATCH(R35,Q5:Q33, 0)

=MATCH(R36, R3:AD3,0)
```

Then I use the index function to give me the cell value corresponding to the row and column number.

```
=INDEX(R5:AD33,S35,S36)
```

I tried to input this as code however it gives me 2 errors I cant solve to proceed debugging.

This line of code below gives me the "assignment to constant not permitted". I'm not sure where the constant is as x is a variable.

```
WorksheetFunction.Match("NPS", Sheets("sheet2").ListObjects("Table1"), 0) = x
```

There was also a user type not defined error but it didn't highlight a particular line of code.

Thanks.

Comment: Match returns a number -- the position of the search term within the search array. So your line of code is attempting to assign the value of x to some number. It's not clear what you intend to do. If you want x to be given the value of the Match result, then swap the Match call and the x, so:x = WorksheetFunction.Match("NPS", Sheets(("sheet2").ListObjects("Table1"),0)

Comment: Without seeing your actual VBA code it looks like Rich is correct.

Comment: I think for the user data type not defined you need to click Tools, References, and either 'Visual Basic for Applications' or the 'Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5...' box. I'm on a GNU/Linux box at the moment or I'd be more specific.